# Deleting nodes in treeview

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I have a tree view as :

```
Car
  BMW
Plane
  Us
```

I have a checkbox besides every node.
Now, when I try to remove Audi by selecting it, nothing happens but when I click on Car, then everything inside it gets deleted.

Could any one please point out where I am wrong.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //if(!IsPostBack)
    form1.Controls.Add(add());        
}

TreeView tv1 = new TreeView();
int count = 0;

public TreeView add()
{       
    TreeNode tn = new TreeNode();
    tn.Text = "car";
    tn.Value = "car";

    TreeNode tn1 = new TreeNode();

tn1.Text = "bmw";
tn1.Value = "bmw";

tn.ChildNodes.Add(tn1);

tv1.Nodes.Add(tn);
tn.ShowCheckBox = true; tn1.ShowCheckBox = true;

TreeNode tn2 = new TreeNode();
tn2.Text = "plane";
tn2.Value = "plane";

TreeNode tn12 = new TreeNode();
tn12.Text = "us";
tn12.Value = "us";

tn2.ChildNodes.Add(tn12);

tv1.Nodes.Add(tn2);
tn2.ShowCheckBox = true; tn12.ShowCheckBox = true;
return tv1;
```

}

```
public void Remove(TreeNode tn)
{
    if (tn.Checked)
    {            
        //tv1.Nodes.Remove(tn);
        if (tn.Parent != null)
            tn.Parent.ChildNodes.Remove(tn);
        else
            tv1.Nodes.Remove(tn);
    }
   else if (tn.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode tn1 in tn.ChildNodes)
        {
            Remove(tn1);   
        }
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    //Remove(tv1.Nodes[0]);
    //Response.Write(count);

    for(int i=0; i < tv1.Nodes.Count; i++)        
          Remove(tv1.Nodes[i]);     
}
```

Comment: Why are you hard-coding `tv1.Nodes[0]` in `Button1_Click` instead of finding the selected node?

Comment: i do not know how to find. and i am passing the root, so every checked nodes would be covered

Comment: I think you need to use `tn.Parent.Nodes.Remove(tn)` if `tn.Parent` is not null, and `tv1.Nodes.Remove(tn)` if `tn.Parent` is null.

Comment: @MichaelLiu i did not understood it

Comment: and tn.Parent.Nodes.Remove(tn) is a wrong command, there is nothing like nodes after parent in tn.Parent.Nodes.Remove(tn)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix remove part.

```
if (tn.Checked)
{       
    if(tn.Parent != null)
       tn.Parent.ChildNodes.Remove(tn);
    else 
       tv1.Nodes.Remove(tn);
}
else if (tn.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
{      
     for(int i=0; i < tn.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
     {
         Remove(tn.ChildNodes[i]);
     }
}
```

**NOTE**:

```
Car
   BMW
   Audi
Truck
```

`tv1.Nodes` always refers to node at first level.

For example if you have checked `Audi` you cannot use because `tv1.Nodes.Remove` would always expect that you want to specify  `Car` and `Truck` nodes.

To remove `Audi` just look for its parent `Car` node and delete from it.

If you want to traverse through all nodes:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
   for(int i=0; i < tv1.Nodes.Count; i++)        
      Remove(tv1.Nodes[i]);       
}
```